# Is it okay to ask a question you don't understand the answer to?

Tags: discussion, questions

I occasionally ask a question about a subject area which interests me, but which I don't have a lot of specialised knowledge about.

The trouble is that sometimes some very good answers which delve much deeper into the subject than I can understand. So what is the correct course of action for questions like this?

- Avoid asking questions which I'm likely to miss the answer to.
- Ask for a simpler explanation, or a source of background information I'm lacking?
- Do nothing, leave the question there for others who may benefit more from the more technical answers.

There may be other approaches to this issue, I'm not sure.

Comment: _" I know that Stack Exchange is about learning"_  Wrong assumption.

Comment: That's an interesting statement, what would you say Stack Exchange is for if not sharing and acquiring information?

Comment: Check what's written here:  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Nope, still basically boils down to learning. Or information sharing.

Comment: @AJFaraday When people come to meta to say that SE is "about learning" what they mean is roughly "SE is like a classroom", or "like mentoring", or "like peer teaching". SE is more like an encyclopedia. Yes, you *can* learn from an encyclopedia but not in the same way you learn from having someone personally guide you. Someone expecting SE sites to provide a classroom, mentoring or peer teaching experience is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: That's incredibly pedantic. And while that statement appears to have gathered a great deal of negative attention, nobody's made an attempt at answering this one. Deleting

Comment: @AJFaraday: At the time you deleted the question, it was merely 15 minutes old, and had less than 20 views. How do you expect to get _any_ answers if you delete the question that quickly?

Comment: @AJFaraday: You make reasonable points, except for claiming that this is in any way "pedantic". It's not.

Comment: Real pedantry is insisting that Stack Exchange *is* about learning - just not in a classroom teaching setting. The problem lies in people not understanding that learning can extend beyond the classroom.

Comment: Hypothetical questions like this are generally answered with blanket statements that serve nobody, like this: _"In general: yes, it's perfectly valid to ask a question about a subject you don't understand, granted that the question follows the [ask] guidelines"_. Please give us a concrete example of what question you don't understand and what question you would ask as a result of that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think the blanket statements are somewhat helpful.  Especially to users not as familiar with SO culture.  The question is tagged [meta-tag:discussion]...

Answer (score 10):

> So what is the correct course of action for questions like this?

Perform sufficient research on your own time so that you understand the basics of the topic.

While a broad variety of "difficulty levels" in both questions and answers is largely to be expected, you should also remain aware that questions and answers — even the questions *you* write — are not intended to be solely for your own benefit. They are always for general consumption. So "dumbing down" the answers to an *arbitrarily* very low difficulty level just because you have yet to perform basic research and learning is counter to our mission.

All that being said, **it's perfectly reasonable to ask for a simple summary to be added to an otherwise complex answer**. I like to write those in bold at the top or bottom of an answer. Like this.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is good, and it gets good answers, I don't see the problem.

You can *always* ask for a simplification of the answer in the answer's comments, if something's unclear.

Basically, *"Ask for a simpler explanation, or a source of background information I'm lacking?"* works, as long as it doesn't turn into a tool / library / documentation request.